# AFNetworking 2 Retry Pattern

Tags: ios, afnetworking-2

I'm using `AFNetworking 2.2.3`, `AFNetworking+AutoRetry 0.0.3` and `AFKissXMLRequestOperation@aceontech 0.0.4`.

I have the following codes to fetch data from server:

```
+ (void)doNetwork {
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFKissXMLResponseSerializer serializer];
    NSDictionary *param = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"someValue", @"someKey", nil];
    [manager POST:@"http://example.com/api/" parameters:param success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
      NSError *error;
      DDXMLDocument *xml = [[DDXMLDocument alloc] initWithXMLString:operation.responseString options:0 error:&error];
      if(error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"Error Parsing XML");
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"FetchAPINotification" object:nil];
      } else {
        NSString *xPath = @"response/status";
        NSArray *arr_status = [xml nodesForXPath:xPath error:nil];
        if(arr_status == nil || arr_status.count == 0) {
          NSLog(@"Status Not Found");
          [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"FetchAPINotification" object:nil];
        } else {
          int status = [[arr_status objectAtIndex:0] intValue];
          if(status == 0) { // OK
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"FetchAPINotification" object:nil userInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"OK", @"status", nil];
          } else if(status == 123) { // Requires Re-login
            [self doLogin];
            // How should I call the method again?
            [self doNetwork];
          } else {
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"FetchAPINotification" object:nil];
          }
        }
      }
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
      NSLog(@"Network Error");
      [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"FetchAPINotification" object:nil];
    } autoRetry:3];
}
```

Here is the explanation:

First of all, I issue a HTTP POST request using `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` with `param`. Then, in success block, if status = 0, post a notification to pre-defined notification observer to mark successful.

If there is any error, I post a notification without `userInfo` to mark the operation is unsuccessful.

However, there is a case that when the server responses status = 123, which means user token has expired and has to re-login to refresh its token.

**My question is:** How can I re-try the operation after re-login?

*Note: I'm not talking about network timeout retry, which I have already implemented.*